# How to create a YAML build pipeline in azure devops for xamarin projects with referenced dot net projects

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I recently moved my sources to azure devOps to use cd/ci and all the other cool stuff.
Now i created my first build pipeline to build the android part of my Xamarin project. But I end up getting an error message, that a resource of a referenced project could not be found and i shall do a package restore and try again.
Now, since i have azure hosted build agents and not self hosted, i have no ways of setting the agent up properly before doing the build.
But i guess there should be some way to properly configure the build pipeline to do all the necessary stuff.
Its just that i have no clue what i should add to my yaml file in order to fix this stuff.

This is the error message i got:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'd:\a\1\s\*****\*****\*****\*****\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

The problem is, that this file should be generated by compiling a referenced project and is not part of a nuget package.

Here is my build pipeline as far as i figured it out by myself.

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- Share/main

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.1.0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'    

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:    
    projectFile: 'Mobile4/Droid/Mobile4.Droid.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs: 
    apksign: false
    zipalign: false
    apkFiles: '$(outputDirectory)/*.apk'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(outputDirectory)'
```

The build always breaks on step XamarinAndroid

I hope you can help me. 
The solution must be out there somewhere, i just cannot see it right now.
Thx in Advance.
Mav

Comment: What's the purpose of "command: restore"? Does it work when you use a macos-latest vmImage instead? Also, could you please share the file structure of your solution? Also did you try to add     #clean: true

Comment: According to the error message, this is a .netcore project and the SDK used is 2.2.105. The file "obj\project.assets.json" depend on the package restore. So, the root cause is your package restore method is not correct, then the file "project.assets.json" have not be restored successfully. In your YAML, the package restore task you used is Nuget restore task, `nuget restore` can not restore the file "project.assets.json" for .netcore project.  You should use `dotnet restore`.

Comment: I think i may have to tell the pipeline where all the necessary packages are located, but i thought this should all be in the project file respectively in the solution file?
When trying to build locally i don't have any issues.

Comment: @Maverick1st Tell the package location in nuget.config file. For pipeline, the package restore process based on the configuration of nuget.config.

Answer (score 2):

> [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5):
>   Error NETSDK1004: Assets file
>   'd:\a\1\s********************\obj\project.assets.json' not found.
>   Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

According to this error message, the project is `.NetCore` and its SDK used is `2.2.105`. For the file "....\obj\project.assets.json", whether the `project.assets.json` exists is **determined** by package restore step. Now, it prompt this could not be found, it means the package restore does not restore this file successfully.

As I mentioned previously, it is a .NetCore project. So you should use `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget restore`. For **.NetCore** project, the `obj` folder restored by `nuget restore` does not contain `project.assets.json` in it.

[image]

So, to solve the issue you meet, you should replace the task Nuget restore as **dotnet restore**: [dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops).

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    vstsFeed: 'e157d03d-******-fc06f9e13177'
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer i'll just check it out and then mark it as solution if it works :)

Comment: @Maverick1st, welcome. If still has issue, don't hesitate to leave comment here~

Comment: one thing i don't understand is, what the value of the vstsFeed argument does. i thought i just need it if i set feedsToUse: 'select'.
Also i tried your snippet, without the vstsFeed: and it failed with a message that it could not find https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/docuware.documentcontentprocessing.annotations/index.json which is perfectly right of course, since it is not hosted by nuget, but was built also from our company. somehow i still have severe problems understanding the build processes behind that build pipelin. Locally everything builds just fine.

Comment: @Maverick1stm, I think that you have known that this task is used to restore package. In Azure devops, the package can come from the Feed which store your customized packages, also we provide one checkbox to let it still restore some official packages from nuget.org. If you do not specified the feed source, as default, it will start finding packages from nuget.org. Since you said the packages was built from your company, here you must specified the feed source. For YAML, you can click "Settings" which displayed on each step to configure it.

Comment: Liang, Unfortunately as far as i understood the process, i cannot create a feed for the nuget package for the reference i need, because i don't have the sources and it is not built with azure devops. 
But there must be somehow a way to integrate already existing nuget packages into a pipeline without rebuilding it, or am i wrong here? Unfortunately the documentation only covers default cases as far as i found out. None of it helped me yet in my special case.

Comment: @Maverick1st, can we make a appointment to create chat here(Or other contact method, such as make a call by using email)? Then we could talk detailed about your special case and show you how to apply it in our Azure Devops artifacts.

Comment: We can do, but I'll be on vacation for the next week. Can i come back to you once i'm back at work?